# Where does general form of solutions to second order linear homogenous ODE with constant coefficients come from?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to understand why solutions of differential equation
$y'' + ay + by = 0$ which can be written as $$(D^2 + aD + b)y = 0 \quad (1),$$
where $Dy = y'$ and $D$ is a linear operator) are in the form they are, namely:

- if eq.1 has two real roots $r_1, r_2$, then $y = c_1 e^{xr_1} + c_2 e^{xr_2},$
- if eq.1 has single real root $r$ then $y = c_1 e^{rx} + c_2 x e^{rx},$
- if eq.1 has complex roots $z_1 = \alpha + \beta i$ and $z_2 = \alpha - \beta i$, then $y = e^{\alpha x}\cdot(c_1 \sin(\beta x) + c_2 \cos(\beta x))$.

I think I understand the case with two real roots (described below, please let me know if it is right), but derivation of other two is still a huge mistery.

###### Case of 2 real roots

If eq.1 has distinct roots $r_0, r_1$, it can be written as $$(D - r_0)(D - r_1)y = 0,$$
which assuming that $y \neq 0$ gives us two options: either $(D - r_0)y  = 0$ or $(D - r_1)y = 0$ (equations include $y$ as $(D - r)$ is an operator and must be applied on something).
$$(D - r_0)y  = 0 \implies Dy - r_0y = 0 \implies Dy = r_0y \implies y' = r_0y \implies y = y_0 = c_0 e^{xr_0}$$
and similarly $y = y_1 = c_1 e^{xr_1}$. Because solutions of such differential equation form a linear space, general solution can be any linear combinations of $y_0$ and $y_1$.

Comment: With a pair of complex conjugate roots, the same argument works. Then Euler's formula turns the complex exponentials into sines and cosines.

Comment: Hint: Let the solution to $(D-r)y=0$ be $y_0$ now solving $(D-r)^2y=0$ reduces to solving $(D-r)y=y_0.$